# AWS DMS doesn't migrate the some special characters in data properly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, dms

I'm trying to perform a homogenous migration (both source and target DB is AWS Aurora MySQL) using AWS DMS. After running the task, it executes properly and migrates whole data. Since, I've turned validations on, I can see some validation failures. On looking further into validation failures I found that some special characters are not being migrated properly by DMS.

For example,

```
Table column: jsondata
Value in source DB: {'key1': 'some data ?'}
after migration looks something like:
Value in target DB: {'key1': 'some data [SUB]'}
```

Happening only for special characters. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and what's the solution? I want a complete duplication of data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you had this problem:

According to the [AWS DMS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReleaseNotes.html) there was a bug with MySQL replication fixed in ver 3.5.1 released on 21-July-2023

> Fixed an issue for MySQL to MySQL replication where AWS DMS changes the character set to UTF16 when migrating an ALTER statement during CDC.